# Can I generate dirt in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I came accross this on the internet it claim that there is a way to generate dirt:

> To generate dirt:
>
> 1. place dirt.
> 2. bonemeal mushroom
> 3. climb on top of the huge mushroom
> 4. place ANOTHER mushroom on top of the huge mushroom
> 5. bonemeal it
> 6. The spot where you placed the second mushroom is now dirt.

So is this true? If not is there any other way to easily obtain dirt without any to begin with?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? I have chests and chests full of useless dirt!

Comment: survival maps like skyblocks

Comment: My question is that wouldnt just having gone into a creative world real quick answered this question for you faster than typing it up here?

Comment: @James but typing it up here makes it so that other people (like me) can see the answer without having to try it.

Comment: Ok, so maybe this exploit doesn't work, per lunboks answer.  It would still be useful to have a way to obtain dirt blocks; are there any?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You used to be able to plant mushrooms on any surface, then make them grow into Huge Mushrooms using Bone Meal. This would, for some reason, convert the tile below the mushroom's stipe to dirt.

This was obviously a bug (as it would allow players to, for example, destroy Bedrock), and was fixed at some point. So no, this is no longer possible.

Comment: Specifically, the bug only existed in 1.8pre1.  It was fixed by the second prerelease.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to the addition of coarse dirt in Minecraft 1.8, you can now craft 2 gravel and 2 dirt into 4 coarse dirt, which can be tilled back into regular dirt using a hoe.

[image: Coarse Dirt Recipe]

Comment: Of course, on the kind of maps you need to do this in, you probably don't have an easy supply of gravel for this.

Comment: I can imagine that some adventure maps that lack large amounts of dirt probably have not been made with this in mind, so they may include gravel. In the case of the original skyblock survival map with a default nether, you can find gravel in there.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dirt#Renewable_acquisition)

> Another way to obtain renewable dirt makes use of moss blocks. Azalea converts the moss block below it into rooted dirt when grown into a tree. In Java Edition, Large spruce trees convert up to about 100 moss blocks into podzol when grown. Since moss can be converted from stone using bone meal, and stone can be renewably generated with water and lava, dirt can be renewably created as long as there is access to water, lava and moss blocks.
>
> A third way to obtain renewable dirt is by buying podzol or rooted dirt from wandering traders. However, only 18 blocks of podzol or 10 blocks of rooted dirt can be purchased from each trader, so this method cannot be performed on a large scale.

Answer (score 0):

### There is a simple way to generate dirt if you have mods.

The mods that I use to do this are:

1. MineFactory Reloaded
2. Ex Nihilo
3. Ender IO (or any item transporting mods)

---

- First you create a "planter" from MFR, and place it below some dirt. Inside you place saplings and set all the filters to saplings.

  The planter from MFR:

  [image]
- Then you give it a supply of energy, I use the Stirling generator for reasons shown later. I simply place the Stirling generator next to the planter.
- Above the dirt, one block aside, I place the harvester (also from MFR). And I can use "Energy Conduit"s from Ender IO to make the Stirling generator below, to share energy with it.
  Note the conduits on the left hand side!

  Where to place the harvester:

  [image]

  The harvester takes trees, when grown, and chops them down, the conduits send the items over to this chest:
- The chest:

  [image]

  The chest then, with the help of conduits, takes the saplings and places them in "barrel"s from Ex Nihilo. These compost the saplings and give dirt. On the underside of the barrels I have placed conduits in 'extract' mode, so they extract the dirt and place it in any chest I want.